# LinqPad does not create list properties for many2many tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linqpad

i'v got two tables e.g.: Man and Woman
And a many2many reference table like Man2Woman.

Is there a way to tell LinqPad to create navigation properties like this:

```
db.Man.Where(x => x.Woman.IsSomething == true)
```

Instead of this

```
db.Man.Where(x => x.Man2Woman.DoSomething)
```

Comment: No. It's just linq-to-sql, which doesn't support many to many.

Comment: You could create an Entity Framework context though. EF supports many-to-many, and you can connect to an EF context in Linqpad.

Comment: Ah okay I see. So I just need to create an Assembly and enter the relevant data in LinqPad?! I will try this :)

Comment: Many-to-many between man and woman spells trouble